# This question appears to be off-topic because it is about <end>

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

When voting to close, it's possible to select a custom close reason. The default text is:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about

I've seen a number of comments auto-added to questions when this option has been selected, but the voter hasn't changed or appended anything to the default text.

[Here's](https://serverfault.com/questions/523550/a-record-redirect-gives-400-bad-request-in-nginx) the latest one I've found. Surely it can't be too hard for SE to not accept the default custom close reason?

Comment: Doing sensible things is apparently *incredible* hard for [SE]. They are all about making the site more useless. This custom close reason is a prime example: I want to close-vote crap as fast as possible and having to write something prevents me from doing this.

Comment: Please go upvote http://stackapps.com/a/4235/1150 then the pro-forma comments author may help out.

Comment: I've already [reported this on mSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185942/189912) some time ago.

Comment: @svw - I don't have a problem with it slowing people down. Forces you to think about what you're doing rather than slinging indescriminantly, and gives the OP a much greater chance of identifying the problem and fixing it next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Validation for this case added in build 2013.7.19.1249 (meta), 2013.7.19.874 (sites)

Comment: ...so I suppose you'll be wanting beer or something as a reward, huh? :P

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185942/189912

Comment: @voretaq7 I'm thinking if I should start accepting bitcoin donations ;)

Answer (score 9):

Erm, it's not empty and they 'grey out' the button if you remove all the text.

[image]

I guess it's an attempt to get people to leave a constructive comment but as ever 'pink and fuffyness' prevails and you're not forced to do so.

To be honest I frequently find it difficult not to

```
s/about/a steaming pile of shit./
```

but whilst it would go down well with the regulars just imagine the whingeing it would cause here on meta so I go with,

```
s/ about/./
```

Comment: If someone who has GM skills could some up with a way to populate and select pro-forma close reasons I could run with that...

Comment: So it is, my bad. Point still stands though.

Comment: I found that using something like TextExpander (whatever is available on your desktop platform) is much easier for this task. I've a row of sf*xxx* macros that get autoexpanded into text.

Comment: Updated question to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

In reality the system should check if the comment is *just* the lead-in text and reject it (***HEY DEVELOPERS!!!*** -- at least a front-end JS check?).
The fact that it doesn't is certainly a [bug](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bug) in my mind.

---

Unfortunately as regards the overall implementation, there are three equally bad choices:

1. **Pre-populate some generic lead-in text**
   This encourages you to be polite with your comment (and encourages a comment).
2. **Don't pre-populate the box at all - Insist people compose a reason for themselves.**
   This is the same as forcing comments on downvotes.
   Also - Seriously? You want to let ***SERVER FAULT USERS*** compose close reasons?

   - `Your question is a festering pile of elephant dung!`
   - `RTFM N00B!`
   - `What kind of IDIOT would attempt this?!`
   - *etc.*
3. **Don't allow custom close comments at all.**
   (Probably the easiest solution but then we have questions closed with no real explanations.)

Comment: I would like to have a simple "is off-topic" close reason which auto generates a link to the topic list of the help center, somewhat like the "duplicate" works.

Comment: Gee, wasn't there a time when we had a simple off-topic close reason?  I guess some meddling moron took it away...